# Script for a Civil War game

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, battle-simulation

I'm new to Python, and pretty much programming/scripting. I'm just looking for someone to critique my methods and tell me if there are more efficient ways to do things.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#
#
# A quick script to create a civil war game


############################
# DECLARE GLOBAL VARIABLES #
############################


### Armies = [Inf,Cav,Art] ###

global compdefmult
global compattmult
global compchoice
global userdefmult
global userattmult
global userchoice
comparmy = [100,50,10]
userarmy = [100,50,10]


##################
# IMPORT MODULES #
##################


import os
from random import randint


##########################
# DEFINE GLOBAL FUNCTIONS #
###########################

def clearscreen():
    os.system('clear')


def newstart():
    clearscreen()
    print ('''

 CCCC  IIIII  V    V  IIIII  L      W   W   W  AA  RRRR
C        I     V  V     I    L       W  W  W  A  A R   R 
C        I      VV      I    L        W W W   AAAA RRRR
 CCCC  IIIII    VV    IIIII  LLLL     WW WW   A  A R   R

This is Civil War!

You will have Infantry, Calvary and Artillery to win the battles you need to turn the tide of the war.

Now, General, take your place in history!

''')

def printstatus():
    print ('Your total Infantry are:' , userarmy[0])
    print ('Your total Calvary are:' , userarmy[1])
    print ('Your total Artillery are:' , userarmy[2])
    print ('')
    print ('Computers total Infantry are:' , comparmy[0])
    print ('Computers total Calvary are:' , comparmy[1])
    print ('Computers total Artillery are:' , comparmy[2])
    print ('')
    mainmenu()


####################
# MAIN BATTLE CODE #    
####################

def compdigger():   
    global compchoice
    global compdefmult
    global compattmult
    compchoice = randint(1,3)
    if compchoice == 1:
        if comparmy[0] == 0:
            compdigger()
        else:
            compchoice = "Infantry"
            compdefmult = 3
            compattmult = 3
    elif compchoice == 2:
        if comparmy[1] == 0:
            compdigger()
        else:
            compchoice = "Calvary"
            compdefmult = 4
            compattmult = 2
    else:
        if comparmy[2] == 0:
            compdigger()
        else:
            compchoice = "Artillery"
            compdefmult = 2
            compattmult = 4
    return compchoice
    return compdefmult
    return compattmult

def takeaction():
    print ('Infantry have an offensive multiplier of 3 and a defensive multiplier of 3')
    print ('Calvary have an offensive multiplier of 2 and a defensive multiplier of 4')
    print ('Artillery have an offensive multiplier of 4 and a defensive multiplier of 2')
    print ('')
    print ('''

Do you want to use:

1) Infantry
2) Calvary
3) Artillery

    ''')
    print ("")
    action = input ("Choose one -> : ");
    if action == "1":
        userchoice = "Infantry"
        print ("")
        if userarmy[0] == 0:
            print ("You don't have any more infantry! Please choose another troop set!")
            takeaction()
        else:
            print ("MAAAAARRRRCH!!!!!")
            defmult = 3
            attmult = 3
            print ("")
    elif action == "2":
        userchoice = "Calvary"
        print ("")
        if userarmy[1] == 0:
            print ("You don't have any more calvary! Please choose another troop set!")
            takeaction()
        else:
            print ("CHAAAAARRRGE!!!!!!")
            defmult = 4
            attmult = 2
            print ("")
    elif action == "3":
        userchoice = "Artillery"
        print ("")
        if userarmy[2] == 0:
            print ("You don't have any more artillery! Please choose another troop set!")
            takeaction()
        else:
            print ("FIIIIIIIRE!!!!!!")
            defmult = 2
            attmult = 4
            print ("")
    else:
        print ("")
        print ("You did not choose 1,2 or 3. Please choose a valid answer")
        print ("")
        takeaction()

    print ("")

    userdefroll = randint(1,12)
    userattroll = randint(1,12)

    print ("Your defensive roll was ", userdefroll)
    print ("Your attack roll was " , userattroll)

    compdefroll = randint(1,12)
    compattroll = randint(1,12)

    print ("")

    print ("Computers defensive roll was " , compdefroll)
    print ("Computers attack roll was " , compattroll)


    print ("")

    userattack = int(attmult) * int(userattroll)
    userdefense = int(defmult) * int(userdefroll)

    print ("")
    print ("Defense total is multiplier %s times roll %s which has a total of %s " % (defmult, userdefroll , userdefense)) 
    print ("Attack total is miltiplier %s times roll %s which has a total of %s " % (attmult, userattroll, userattack))
    print ("")

    compdigger()

    compdefense = int(compdefmult) * int(compdefroll)
    compattack = int(compattmult) * int(compattroll)

    print ("")
    print ("The computer chose ", compchoice)
    print ("")
    print ("Computers total Defense multiplier is %s times it's roll %s which has a total of %s " % (compdefmult, compdefroll, compdefense))
    print ("Computers total Attack multiplier is %s times it's roll %s which has a total of %s " % (compattmult, compattroll, compattack))
    print ("")

    print ("")
    if compdefense >= userattack:
        print ("The computer defended your attack without troop loss")
    else:
        userdiff = int(userattack) - int(compdefense)
        print ("Computer lost %s  %s " % (userdiff , compchoice))
        if compchoice == "Infantry":
            comparmy[0] -= int(userdiff)
            if comparmy[0] < 0:
                comparmy[0] = 0
        elif compchoice == "Calvary":
            comparmy[1] -= int(userdiff)
            if comparmy[1] < 0:
                comparmy[1] = 0
        else:
            comparmy[2] -= int(userdiff)
            if comparmy[2] < 0:
                comparmy[2] = 0 

    if userdefense >= compattack:
        print ("You defended the computers attack without troop loss")
    else:
        compdiff = int(compattack) - int(userdefense)
        print ("You lost %s  %s " % (compdiff , userchoice))
        if userchoice == "Infantry":
            userarmy[0] -= int(compdiff)
            if userarmy[0] < 0:
            userarmy[0] = 0
        elif userchoice == "Calvary":
            userarmy[1] -= int(compdiff)
            if userarmy[1] < 0:
                userarmy[1] = 0
        else:
            userarmy[2] -= int(compdiff)
            if userarmy[2] < 0:
                userarmy[2] = 0

    if userarmy[0] == 0 and userarmy[1] == 0 and userarmy[2] == 0:
        print ("Your army has been decemated! RETREAT!")
        exit(0)

    if comparmy[0] == 0 and comparmy[1] == 0 and comparmy[2] ==0:
        print ("The computers army has been decemated! VICTORY!")
        exit(0)

    print ("")


    mainmenu()


def mainmenu():
    print ('''

MAIN MENU
---------

1) Print out army status
2) ATTACK!
3) Save game (not implemented yet)
4) Load game (not implemented yet)
5) Quit

''')

    menuaction = input ("Please choose an option -> : ");
    if menuaction == "1":
        printstatus()
    elif menuaction == "2":
        takeaction()
    elif menuaction == "3":
        print ("Not implemented yet!")
        mainmenu()
    elif menuaction == "4":
        print ("Not implemented yet!")
        mainmenu()
    elif menuaction == "5":
        print ("Good bye!")
        exit (0)
    else:
        print ("You did not choose 1,2,3 or 4. Please choose a valid option!")
        mainmenu()

newstart()
mainmenu()
```

Comment: A few quick notes: If you want to loop forever, use `while True:`, not a function that calls itself recursively. You can use `random.choice(['Infantry', 'Cavalry', 'Artillery'])` instead of using `randint(1, 3)` and then comparing to 1, 2, and 3. And you can use a dict mapping inputs to functions instead of a long if-elif chain that just does the same thing manually.

Comment: One more thing: to return three numbers, do `return compchoice, compdefmult, compattmult`. If you do three separate `return` statements, only the first one gets executed. Also, the caller should actually store those returned values somewhere and use them. And if you do that, you can get rid of all of the globals.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by

>"the caller should actually store those returned values somewhere and use them"

I've always wondered what the solution around getting rid of globals would be. Can you elaborate a bit? 

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: Also about the returns, so currently as written, only the value for compchoice is being returned?

Comment: Exactly, only the `compchoice` is being returned.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned by [@abarnert](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/27320/abarnert), you're using infinite recursion to *"repeat forever"*. By default, after you've recursed more than 1000 times, your program will throw an error. The better way to do this would be to use a `while condition` loop. In this case, your `takeaction` function would become this:

```
def take_action() -> None:
    """
    Add a description of take_action here.
    """
    while True:
        ...
```

---

You can also use a dictionary of functions containing actions rather than chaining `if condition` statements. Usually it's looks better. Here's a basic example of what that could look like:

```
def my_action() -> None:
    """
    Description
    """
    ...

actions = {
    "action": my_action
}

user_input = raw_input()
if user_input in actions:
    actions[user_input]()
```

---

I'd also recommend using [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to document how your code works. They're very important, because they describe how your code works. Without them, code can be understandable, but can be very hard to understand. Here's an example:

```
def my_function(args) -> None:
    """
    Add a description of the function here.
    """
    ...
```

---

Your `clearscreen()` function isn't very portable, and will only work on linux-based systems. I'd recommend using something like this instead:

```
def clear_screen():
    os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "clear")
```

---

Finally, I'd recommend reading [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), Python's official style guide. It essentially tells you how your code should be formatted, and how it should look. If you want to check your code for PEP8 issues, you can use [this online checker.](http://pep8online.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

If I used a dictionary that contained actions, wouldn't I still need to use an if statement to call those? Do you have a link to an example so I can take a look?

Also is the 1000 recurses something that's configurable? Just wondering? I'll replace with the while do loop now.

I'll run through the style checker, but was there something specific you saw that was a big no no?

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: @ChrisGleason: No, you don't need an `if` statement for each action if you have a dictionary; that's the whole point. You either need a single `if` statement, like Ethan showed here, or no `if` statements at all if you call `actions.get(user_input, handle_bad_input)`.

Comment: Just ran through the pep8 checker. Looks like I've got a lot of reading to do!

Comment: @ChrisGleason: Meanwhile, the most obvious PEP 8 violation is putting spaces between the function name and the `(` in most of your function calls. (And the fact that it's most, but not all, makes it inconsistent, which is an even bigger no-no.)

Comment: @ChrisGleason Technically, yes, the recursion is "configurable", but it then can only be set to a maximum of `2^31 - 1`. While that's a lot, it's still a bad design.

Comment: I just noticed that you're implicitly suggesting using PEP 484 type hints. Do you think that's worth recommending for code reviews on Python 3 code? (It's not a bad idea, since they're harmless in 3.0-3.4 and may be helpful in 3.5+, I'm just worried about having to explain unfamiliar features that to novices when they can't just look them up in the docs.)

Comment: @abarnert If you feel the need to take them out, or add a reference to PEP484, I'm fine with either. I just prefer to be a little more explicit with my Python.

Comment: @EthanBierlein Not at all! I was just considering whether I should start doing the same thing myself.

Comment: @abarnert It all depends. If explicit is how you want to go, that's okay, if not, that's fine too. That's the beauty of programming :)

Answer (score 8):

The biggest problem in this code is using recursive function calls instead of looping, as I explained in my comment and [Ethan Bierlein's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/91605/27320) explains in a lot more detail. (Note that you're doing this in more than one place—e.g., `compdigger` calls itself instead of looping too. You'll want to fix all of them, not just one.)

The second biggest problem is the way you're passing and returning values to and from your functions.

At the end of `compdigger`, you do this:

```
return compchoice
return compdefmult
return compattmult
```

The first `return` statement exits the function, returning the `compchoice` value. The other statements never happen.

If you want to return three values, put them all in one `return` statement:

```
return compchoice, compdefmult, compattmult
```

(Technically, this is still only returning a single value, which just happens to be a tuple whose three members are the three values you wanted to return. But you can ignore that detail for now.)

Meanwhile, a `return` doesn't do any good unless someone actually uses the returned value. But you never do; you just call `compdigger()`. If you're going through all the trouble to return three values, you should assign them to three variables:

```
compchoice, compdefmult, compattmult = compdigger()
```

And once you do that, there's no reason for your `global` statements. Instead of modifying three global variables, `compdigger` is just returning 3 values; instead of accessing the global variables, `takeaction` is just accessing its own local variables, which it set from the result of calling `compdigger()`.

The `comparmy` variable is being used, but not modified, within `compdigger`, so you can pass that as arguments. Change the definition to:

```
def compdigger(comparmy):
```

… and the call to:

```
compchoice, compdefmult, compattmult = compdigger(comparmy)
```

You still have four more globals—`userchoice`, `userdefmult`, `userattmult`, and `userarmy`—but those are only being used at all within `takeaction`, so there's no reason for them to be globals in the first place.

And, once you've removed all of those, you have no non-constant global variables left, which is what you're aiming for.

---

My next suggestion was to use a dict as a function lookup table instead of a big `elif` chain; Ethan Bierlein's answer again covers that in a lot more detail.

---

Next, if you have three values to choose from, instead of this:

```
if i == 1:
    i = 'Infantry'
elif i == 2:
    i = 'Cavalry'
elif i == 3:
    i = 'Artillery'
```

… you can use a `dict` again, like this:

```
forces = {1: 'Infantry', 2: 'Cavalry', 3: 'Artillery'}
i = forces[i]
```

And if you share that `forces` dict between the user-turn and computer-turn code, your computer code just does:

```
i = forces[random.randint(1, 3)]
```

… or, maybe even better:

```
i = random.choice(forces.values())
```

---

At the top of `takeaction`, you're mixing a bunch of separate one-line `print` calls and one multi-line `print` call. There might sometimes be a good reason for that, but I don't see why here you're not just using one big multi-line call. And if you did that, you could fit your source code into 80 columns, which makes it more readable for people who want to read it on such obsolete places as default-sized terminal windows, emacs frames, or StackOverflow questions.

---

`os.system('clear')` isn't portable. On Windows, the corresponding command is called `cls`, not `clear`. And even on non-Windows systems, it's not guaranteed by POSIX, it just happens to be part of the GNU and BSD userland—which is fine if you care only about, say, Mac, Linux, and FreeBSD, but not if you want it to work on all Unix systems.

There is no actual portable way to do what you want (short of printing a bunch of blank lines and assuming that's probably good enough), and that may be fine, just be aware that you're limiting your portability.

---

If you want to push your learning a little bit farther, this game would make a great way for you to learn about classes. You have some clearly-definable objects here: the `Game` object, two `Player` objects, one of which is an `AIPlayer` subclass, and maybe even `Unit` objects with three subclasses (although I personally don't think I'd model the units that way). This is obviously a pretty big change, and it's definitely not necessary to make your code good; it's just a different way to think of the same program, and you would learn a lot by trying to redesign it that way.

---

Meanwhile, this isn't really a comment on your code, but on your question: asking for a "more efficient" way to do something is usually not a useful question.

"Efficient" can mean different things—less CPU time, less total time, less heat generated, less memory or disk space used, or even less development time. These are often tradeoffs—e.g., you can make it faster by using more memory—so just "more efficient" is in general impossible to answer.

More importantly, it's usually not relevant. For example, if your game is running more fast enough, never going over 10% CPU usage, and only using 46K of memory, how would it benefit you to make it faster or less CPU-hungry or smaller? Making your code less readable to make it more efficient is a bad tradeoff when it's already efficient enough. And, even when your code *isn't* efficient enough, it's almost always some particular bottleneck that's inefficient, and that's the only part you want to optimize; everything else, you're better off with readable code than efficient code.

Of course there are some cases where code is just algorithmically bad (e.g., if you're doing a quadratic search where you could have done an instant lookup), but usually in those cases, the more efficient code is also more readable and idiomatic anyway.

---

Finally, while this isn't a problem in your game logic, two issues with your text.

First, some of your output is wider than 80 columns. Most people run command-line programs in an 80-column terminal window, so for example, your game banner will look something like:

```
You will have Infantry, Calvary and Artillery to win the battles you need to turn t
he tide of the war.
```

Second, you've misspelled "cavalry" as "calvary", multiple times. The first one means soldiers on horses with sabres; the second one means a representation of Jesus's crucifixion. A civil war grognard will sneer at your game for that. :)

Comment: lol. Thanks. Haven't had time to read through all of this yet, but i will tonight.

Thanks for all the feedback!

Comment: `os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "clear")` is the most portable way to clear the screen atm.

Comment: @EthanBierlein More portable than `os.system('clear')`, sure, but hardly "the most portable". That will still fail or do the wrong thing on systems with a minimal userland, or when the program is run inside IDLE, etc. A more portable thing would probably be to check `isatty`, then check for termcaps (or maybe try `curses` first), then fall back to the ANSI/VT100 sequence or the `clear` command only if there's no termcap lib. What matters is what's "portable enough" for the intended uses. (If he only cares about running interactively in Terminal.app on his Mac, he's already done.)

Comment: Since you're both commenting on this I'll comment here since you'll both be notified. I was finally getting back to this and came across this [link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) when looking into formatting while loops. What do you think about them saying while loops are significantly slower? I think in this particular case, it's probably negligent, and I'm sure nesting recursive functions probably is slow too but wanted to see what yo thought of it.

Still reformatting my code and trying to figure out how to rip my functions out of recursion and put them into a while loop.

Comment: @ChrisGleason The problem with recursive function calls isn't about it being fast or slow - the problem is, using a recursive call to loop "forever" will cause your program to eventually crash if someone plays your game a long time. The 'while' loop doesn't have that problem. The page you linked to is talking about the relative speed of 'while True' vs. 'while 1', which is probably negligent in any case. I would use 'while True' because it seems to be more common in Python code.

Comment: @ChrisGleason The wiki page doesn't say while loops are slower than recursive calls; it says `while True:` loops with an `if done: break` inside are slower than `while not done:` loops. That's true, but they're both _much_ faster than recursion. And as @Brandin says (and my answer), robustness trumps speed anyway--and so does readability, except in special cases.